# Problem with Excel interop application with Office 2016

Tags: c#, excel-interop

I am having trouble with an application that uses Excel interop. With Excel 2010 and 2013 it works perfectly fine. Unfortunately it no longers works for my colleague now that he has upgraded to Office 2016. I will also upgrade very soon and need to find a solution.

What is being done?

A click event fires a background worker...

```
private void btnPrep_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    lblWorking.Visible = true;
    pBar1.Visible = true;
    //...
    //...
    bwPrep.RunWorkerAsync(args);
}
```

... which in turn calls a method "Xls2Xml"...

```
private void bwPrep_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
{
    //...
    //...
    foreach (var x in y)
    {
        var fils = di.GetFiles();
        if (fils.Any(f => f.Name.Contains(".xls"))) 
        {
            bwPrep.ReportProgress(0, lang);
            Xls2Xml(fils.First(f => f.Name.Contains(".xls")).FullName, dest);
        }   
    }
}
```

... in which I use interop:

```
private void Xls2Xml(string xlsPath, string destination)
{
    var pfad = xlsPath;
    var xlapp = new XL.Application();
    var wbooks = xlapp.Workbooks;
    var wb = wbooks.Open(pfad);
    var sheets = wb.Sheets;
    XL.Worksheet sheet = sheets[1];
    //...
    //...
    Marshal.ReleaseComObject(sheet);
    Marshal.ReleaseComObject(sheets);
    Marshal.ReleaseComObject(wb);
    Marshal.ReleaseComObject(wbooks);
    Marshal.ReleaseComObject(xlapp);
}
```

This works fine with Excel 2010 and 2013. Excel 2016 causes a COM error. First, it was RPC_E_SERVERCALL_RETRYLATER ("application busy").

Googling gave me a recommendation to add this line before calling the background worker:

```
System.Threading.SynchronizationContext.SetSynchronizationContext(new WindowsFormsSynchronizationContext());
```

What this did was to change the resulting error into "Call was rejected by callee" (RPC_E_CALL_REJECTED).

I made sure that the correct versions of Excel interop and Office library are referenced (1.9 / 16).

The error occurs on the line `var xlapp = new XL.Application();`, no other instance of Excel application is created before this line. Excel is properly installed and activated, a repair installation did not solve the issue either.

Have any of you come across similar issues?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved.

It turned out to be something my colleague conveniently forgot to mention because he completely forgot about it: the culprit was the **Kutools** Add-In.

Although it was installed before and hadn't caused problems back then, one of the latest Office updates must have changed some behavior. Deactivating Kutools was all it took.